# Oracle Apex 2 actions not performed together in modal dialog buttons

Tags: oracle-apex

I have 3 buttons on a pop-up page.

DEACTIVATE-> Used to uncheck checkbox item P1_ACTIVE in the same pop-up

UPDATE_NULL -> Set page item in the interactive grid in the main page to null and closes dialog.

UPDATE-> Submit and close the dialog.

The problem is when i use DEACTIVE AND UPDATE_NULL separately they work just fine.

But when i use them together, i.e. try to uncheck P1_aCTIVE box and then click on UPDATE_NULL. I want both to happen, i.e P1_ACTIVE is unchecked and in IG it has a column which would show as N.
Also with update_nul another column would be set to null.

Now UPDATE_NULL has a process with pl/sql as  :P1_ACTIVE :=null;

And DEACTIVATE is button defined by dynamic action with set value P1_ACTIVE :=N.

There is a close dialog process in the page processing part also currently with no conditions.

How can i change the settings such that when i click on DEACTIVATE and then UPDATE_NULL, both P1_aCTIVE is set to N and te IG column is set to null and not either of the two at a time?

I am sorry i cannot provide example or screenshots so please let me know if there are any questions related to requirement.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what you mean. As in most cases, it's best to reproduce your issue using the sample emp/dept tables. If you do so, you can share screenshots or even build a test case on apex.oracle.com